# How to reverse engineer a .RIB file?

Tags: java, gps, notepad++, reverse-engineering, gpx

In 2019 I bought a [Zeal Optics Transcend GPS](https://www.pocket-lint.com/gadgets/reviews/72254-zeal-transcend-gps-goggles-review) goggle for a very low price.

These google were produced by [Recon Instruments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recon_Instruments) and they were later bought by Intel. The technology was very good an I was able to check my statistics during the day and at home.

[image]

Because the googles hit the market on 2012/2013 the technology was a bit old when I bought them but I was still able to upload my data to http://reconinstruments.com/ and I could check online my statistics

[image]

Then, some day around 2020 the dashboard wasn't reachable any more, the website was down, and all the Zeal Optics Transcend GPS goggle owner were left alone without any way to upload the data to a dashboard.

But the monitor on the goggle is still working, collecting data, and if I connect the goggle to my computer I can see a DAY08.RIB file that is generated for each day I go to ski.

The files on Notepad++ looks something like this:

[image]

Because internet is a fantastic place to be I found someone else in my [same situation](https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/Recon-Instruments-UPLINK-Snow-2/m-p/1200190?profile.language=en) and on the Intel blog someone suggested to use [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/evilwombat/flight-converter) which contains a .jar and a .java file to convert the *.RIB to *.GPX.

The repository works very well!

But is missing temperature information.

Is there any way I could reverse engineer a .RIB file because I think that the temperature information are not taken during the conversion. But they must be there. Somewhere.

**EDIT:** In case you want to download a copy I put 3 of them [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArldK_gE2gPUkK1oaHHffeZlLR2Gwg?e=U120hs)

**EDIT 2:** New data fresh out of the fridge [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArldK_gE2gPUkK1vJWADDolZQarr2A?e=hEZgj8) . As you can see there are 2 files that get generated for each day: DAY14 and EVENT14 but the second one is nearly empty. The goggle started at 14° and said in the fridge 30 minutes. When I took them out of the fridge the temperature on the monitor was 8° and the max reached was 15°.

Comment: To reverse engineer any binary file, you first need to bring it up in a [file dump viewer](https://github.com/ggleblanc2/file-dump#readme).

Comment: Exactly @GilbertLeBlanc, I tried multiple ASCII to text/string converters online but I wasn't able to find one. I have no idea what I'm dealing with. How can I find the format of this blob?

Comment: You can try this online [RIB file reader](https://filext.com/file-extension/RIB).  User beware.,

Comment: Hey, @StackOverflow, why my question was labelled as "opinion based". My question is based on facts: screenshots and raw data. Where are the opinions? Help me understand, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coincidentally I just shared a project on github which I made to do exactly what you're asking, but this is for the Snow2 goggles of Recon Instruments. Here is the repository: https://github.com/stevenhgs/rib-to-gpx-file-converter

In the README you can see how I was able to reverse engineer it.

After taking a quick look at your files I saw that the data of your files do not have the same structure as the files produced by the Snow2 goggles. So the program I shared won't work for your files. However, I was able to see that your track points have a size of 20 and I was able to already see the time, the longitude and latitude in this data.

Is it correct that the activity of the file DAY05.rib took place around 16:48 and at a latitude of 46.xxx and a longitude of 6.xxx?

Comment: This is what I call Reverse Engineering. Thank you @stevenhgs. Yes, I confirm that your time, lat, lon are correct. Can you spot info about the temperature? Thank you

Comment: @Francesco Mantovani, I think it is the byte at index 21, I updated my project to support the type of files created by Zeal Optics Transcend GPS goggles. Is it maybe possible to let your goggles record and put them in the freezer for 10 minutes and then get them out of the freezer for 10 minutes. This way it will be easy to see on the graph what data represents the temperature. It would be nice if you could send me that file after you have done that. Is it also okay if I add you DAY04.rib file to my project?

Comment: Please, add the DAY04.rib to your project and if you need I can send you 2 weeks of examples. I added the new file in the post description. Thanks a million for your help. Keep in mind that the temperature might be converted to Celsius / Fahrenheit? On my googles is currently on Celsius

Comment: @Francesco Mantovani, thanks for the new file! I plotted the data of the 3 missing byte values [here](https://imgur.com/a/Cp8BK61). As you can see the byte at index 21 shows the expected result. However, are you sure 18 degrees celsius was the max temperature reached? because I suspect the mapping is: temperature = byte_value - 40. This would be right with your lowest value which is 48 on the graph. The reason why I think it is -40 is because the goggles of my brother have the value of byte 21 constant on 40. Which I think means that this sensor is broken and reads 0 degrees.

Comment: @Francesco Mantovani, are you sure the DAY14.rib file is of the recording of when you put your goggles in the fridge? because it seems like this of an activity which started at 9:20 and ended at 12:08.

Comment: that's strange, I just kept the goggle in the fridge for 30 minutes. I will setup the time correctly and try again tomorrow to see if the file DAY15.rib is generated. Also: I can setup the time but not the date, so the date is still on 2020. Not sure how can I change that

Comment: Maybe there are no files generated if there is not enough distance travelled. Yeah, don't worry about the date, that data isn't included in the files. Make sure when you record to note what temperature it is when it goes in the fridge, what temperature it is when it goes out the fridge and what temperature it is when you stop the recording. And it would be nice if you note the times with it too. Thanks for doing it by the way!

Comment: Yeah, I did it right now, no DAY15.rib was generated. should I send you the DAY14.rib again? It stayed in the fridge from 11:50 to 12:20 and went form 15° to 8°

Comment: Naahhh, the DAY14.rib is still 194Kb. I will now delete all the files and tomorrow I will move on a bike with the goggles. Maybe because it's in the fridge it cannot lock on a GPS satellite and therefore it doesn't record? But it must record the temperature somewhere. 
Let's see tomorrow. Thank you for your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245209/discussion-between-stevenhgs-and-francesco-mantovani).

Comment: Thank you @stevenhgs, I wrote a post about your massive effort: https://www.jeeja.biz/2022/06/14/reverse-engineer-zeal-optics-transcend-gps/

Answer (score 0):

First GPX goal is not to provide full activity formatting but only geo route via waypoints. That said, you could add your temperature value to your GPX file via same code as repo you shared (by forking repo to implement it, by submitting a PR, or asking for feature).

BUT, keep in mind that
**You may experience difficulties using them and get your temperature values in any standard GPX Viewer**
(technically possible to use them, but GPX with custom values could break parsing in some of them)

Lastly, I think you could open your RIB file with another software to get values in the good Charset (didn't try it but it seems like your encounter Windows CP1252 conversion in NotePad++). That could enable you to have a wider view of what you need to do to get values mapped through Formats.

### Post Script

IMHO best solution would be using another format that supports these kind of values Out of the Box, like TCX for example (bit outdated but usecase is sport activities oriented text formatting). Thus it would require you to write a new Rib to Tcx converter yourself.

Comment: Thank you @jacouille . How can I spot the temperature in that ASCII blob? I tried to convert it to Windows CP1252 but it doesn't change much. GPX viewers are human readable but the RIB are not human readable at all. How can I Reverse Engineer something that I cannot read?

Comment: That's not what you think. Windows CP1252 is default Windows Charset, so when you open file it's opened as Windows CP1252. You'll have to try opening it as UTF-8. If you still cannot open Rib files, upload one and send link so i can help you.

Comment: Hi jacouille, I added 1 line to my post, you can download 3 files from there. Thank you so much for your help.